# Composer installation error - file is not within the allowed path

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install composer on windows (symfony 2 project). The problem is that I always get some strage errors - that a couple of files are not in the allowed path.

I've tried a couple of methods to install compsoer:

1. Downloading raw composer.phar file, throwing it into the symfony2 root folder and running composer installation command. It gives me an error that usr/.../composer/.htaccess is not within the allowed path
2. php -r "path" gives similar results as above, but with more "not in the allowed path" errors
3. Windows installer - it throws an error that the installer couldn't execute php.exe file, no idea why.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust `open_basedir` in your **php.ini** to include the path to your project and the other paths that composer tries to load from/write to. The variable accepts multiple paths separated by `:` (unix) or `;` (windows).

```
open_basedir = "/home/sites/yoursites/:/tmp/:/"
```

... or remove the restriction completely from **php.ini**.

```
; remove open_basedir completely ...
; <nothing here>

; ... comment it out like this ...
; open_basedir = "..." 

; ... or set it to an empty value like this ...
open_basedir =
```

You can find the location of the correct php.ini for the CLI sapi with:

```
php --ini
```

Answer (score 1):

- **First**, you should make sure that the path of `php.exe` is in your `ENV` (Environment variable);
- **Second**, if composer's windows installer can't install, just try to use "Run With Administrator Permission", and if it also does not work, just comment me your error.